# Updated Crystal Reports project from VS2005 to VS2010 and reports generate extremely slow

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2010

I have in front of me a Crystal Reports project. It was first done in Visual Studio 2005 and is now being converted to Visual Studio 2010. 2005 used merge modules and the approach is a bit different in 2010 as I have understood it.

After some fiddling around I got it to compile and the installer to package the application. Everything seemed to work fine but then I notice that some reports against some databases takes a loooooong time to generate. I'm talking 15 minutes or something like that. And after a report that takes this long to generate is finally done any other report I try to generate after that comes out empty of data. I have to restart the application to get data in the reports again.

When looking at the program I have come to the conclusion that it's using the [Crystal Reports Helper class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15024/Crystal-Reports-helper-class) from Code Project.

I have tried profiling the app and it seems like the thing that is taking so much time is within Crystal Reports itself and not some function within the current application.

Has anyone, who has updated from Visual Studio 2005 to Visual Studio 2010 and been using the helper class, experienced any similar issues and have any pointers of what to try? Is there perhaps something in how the data is sent from the helper class that is not compatible with the new way Crystal Reports works with Visual Studio 2010?

Some reports work just fine.
Feels like I'm fumbling a bit in the dark.

To rule out incompatibility issues, the SAP specific thing installed are

- Crystal Reports 10
- SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .Net Framework 4 (32-bit)
- SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .Net Framework 4 (64-bit)
- SAP Crystal Reports version for Visual Studio 2010

Comment: If I remember well CR is making by default verification of the database it is trying to connect to - it verifies the structure of views, procedures, etc. After converting to VS 2010 check if database verification is turned on - if yes that may cause your report work slow.

Comment: Where should I look to find this? On the Report Viewer control or what?